# Kotlin - Convert Collection to Array List

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I'm converting a Java application to Kotlin.
In one area it's using apache IO's FileUtils listFiles functions.

These return collections and I'm having problems converting/casting the collections into ArrayList

```
        val myFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(mediaStorageDir, extensions, true) as ArrayList<File>
```

Whilst this compiles I get a runtime error as follows:

> java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

What's the correct way to convert a collection object into an ArrayList?

Comment: `as` is a cast operator, not a conversion operator. Use a method call such as `toList()`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`ArrayList` is a class with implementation details. `FileUtils` is returning a `LinkedList` and that is why you are having issues. You should do a cast to `List<File>` instead since it is an interface that both ArrayList and LinkedList implement.

If you would need to modify the returned list you can use `MutableList<File>` instead the immutable one.

But this is not the best approach because if the creators of `FileUtils` later change the implementation details of their collections your code may start crashing.

A better soulition if explicitly need it to be an arrayList instead of a generic list could be:

```
val myFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(mediaStorageDir, extensions, true)
val array = arrayListOf<File>()
array.addAll(myFiles)
```

Comment: That gives me 
Type mismatch.
Required:
Collection<File>
Found:
(MutableCollection<Any?>..Collection<*>?) at the addAll

Comment: What is the return type of the listFiles method?

Comment: public static Collection listFiles(

Comment: try with: `array.addAll(myFiles as Collection<File>)`
But bear in mind that this is not a completly safe option

Comment: I've updated my Apache Commons version from 1.3 to 2.4 which returns Collection<File> - this seems to be making life easier!

Answer (score 54):

You can easily create `ArrayList` in Kotlin from any `Collection`

```
val collection = FileUtils.listFiles(mediaStorageDir, extensions, true)
val arrayList = ArrayList(collection)
```

Answer (score 11):

The `as` operator is a cast.  But **a cast does not *convert* a value to a given type; a cast claims that the value is *already* of that type.**

A `LinkedList` is not an `ArrayList`, so when you claim it is, the computer will call you out on your mistake — as you see!

Instead, you need* to *convert* the value.  Perhaps the best way is to call the extension function `.toArrayList()`.  Alternatively, you could call the constructor explicitly: `ArrayList(…)`.

(* This assumes you actually need an `ArrayList`.  In practice, it's usually much better to refer only to the interface, in this case `List` or `MutableList`.  As per other comments, the function you're calling is declared to return a `Collection`; the current implementation may return a `LinkedList` for you now, but that could change, so it's safest not to assume it implements either of those interfaces, and instead to call `.toList()` or `.toMutableList()`.)